# C# get thread classes to communicate back to the main class

Tags: c#, .net

I have some C# threads that have to do some work based on numbers however I am unsure how to get the thread objects to communicate back to the main program class. I need it to tell the main object that it has found the result and what the result is, then it can stop the threads.

```
        Worker Worker1 = new Worker(input, 1073741824, 2147483647);
        Worker Worker2 = new Worker(input, 0, 1073741824);
        Thread ThreadRace1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Worker1.Start));
        Thread ThreadRace2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Worker2.Start));
        ThreadRace1.Start();
        ThreadRace2.Start();
```

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Which version of .Net ? If V4+, you can use Task class which is very easy to use.

Comment: Return from your workers when done and join the threads.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET 4.0+, then you can use the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx). The code would look something like this:

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(()=>
    {
        //Do Work...use closures, or you can pass boxed arguments in
        //via StartNew params
        return 1;//return the value that was computed
    });
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew<int>(()=>
    {
        //Do Work
        return 2;//return the value that was computed
    });
task1.ContinueWith((previousTask)=>
    {
        //Return back to the main thread
        label1.Text += "The value of task1 is going to be 1-->" 
                       + previousTask.Result;
    }
    , new CancellationTokenSource().Token, TaskContinuationOptions.None,
    //This is to auto invoke back into the original thread
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); 
task2.ContinueWith((previousTask)=>
    {
        //Return back to the main thread
        label1.Text += "The value of task2 is going to be 2-->" 
                       + previousTask.Result;
    }
    , new CancellationTokenSource().Token, TaskContinuationOptions.None,
    //This is to auto invoke back into the original thread
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

If you dont need to deal with each one as they come in, then you can wait for them all to return:

```
var taskList = new List<Task>{task1,task2};
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(taskList.ToArray(), 
    (tasks)=>
    {
        label1.Text = "Results are: ";
        foreach(var task in tasks)
        {
            //process each task
            label1.Text += task.Result + "|";
        } 
    }, 
    new CancellationTokenSource().Token, TaskContinuationOptions.None,
    //This is to auto invoke back into the original thread
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Comment: I am just wondering though, how can I get the object to pass data back as soon as it has found the answer?

Comment: Updated my response assuming that you are returning an int

Answer (score 1):

There already is a framework class called [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) that is designed to help you in minimizing the amount of code you need to write to perform background processing.  You can have your main thread register to various callback events on the BackgroundWorker, in particular the "OnRunWorkerCompleted" event when the BackgroundWorker thread finishes executing its task.

Here is a quick example of how you set it up.  You will start the BackgroundWorker instances in your main thread.

```
    void SetupBackgroundworkers()
    {
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);

        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker2 = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundWorker2.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker2_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker2_RunWorkerCompleted);

        // Start the workers
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void backgroundWorker2_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var result = e.Result; // read result
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var result = e.Result; // read result
    }

    void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // perform work...
        e.Result = 1;  // your result
    }

    void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // perform work...
        e.Result = 2;  // your result
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

1. pass a reference of the main class to each Worker via the Worker's constructor. This way you can call a `public` method exposed by the main class
2. call a `public static` method exposed by the main class (the dirtiest solution; avoid it at all costs)
3. if you're using C# 4.0, you can use the Task Parallel Library's [WaitAny](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdykks7z.aspx) method to get control in the main class when *any* of the workers have finished

The first two options require explicit concurrency control measures (make sure after one worker signaled the main class, no other worker can).

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

set a global variable from within the thread (but then you will have synchronisation issues if multiple threads are using same vars)

OR

Use ParameterisedThreadStart which allows the passing of an object (which you can use an out (by reference) variable.

OR you can create a threadmanager class which has a method to be called on completion by any thread it starts - the method could be of signature (but this is up to you and mine is semi-psuedocode)

```
static class ThreadManager{

    ctor Main(blah blah){//do thread creation and in loop you can call Threadmanager.ThreadFinished as it is static method}

    public static object ThreadFinished(Thread theThreadThatJustFInished, object data)
    {
        //do update on ThreadManager based on object data and Thread type
    }

}
```